# Any issues with JDK and Visual Studio on the same machine?

Tags: visual-studio, java

Is it ok to install the latest JDK to run IntelliJ-IDEA as well as have VS 2008 on the same machine?

Answer (score 1):

Yes. Java doesn't have any dependencies on the .NET framework and vice-versa, so you shouldn't expect any problems.

Answer (score 1):

i have eclipse, intellij-idea, netbeans and vs on the same machine and i did not get any problem just because of this.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. The two will not cause problems with each other.